# Need MYSQL help for senior high school

Tags: mysql

Can you help me with this problem?

"Last name of supervisors of employees in department 5 who work more than 10 hrs/week on productx."

Code:

```
SELECT LNAME FROM EMPLOYEE e , WORKS_ON w, PROJECT p
WHERE e.DNO=5 AND e.SUPER_SSN=w.ESSN AND w.PNO=PNUMBER AND p.PNAME='ProductX' AND HOURS>10;
```

It is same as the one like:

"Last name of employees in department 5 who work more than 10 hrs/week on productx."

with the running code:

```
SELECT LNAME FROM EMPLOYEE e , WORKS_ON w, PROJECT p
WHERE e.DNO=5 AND e.SSN=w.ESSN AND w.PNO=PNUMBER AND p.PNAME='ProductX' AND HOURS>10;
```

But I can't seem to get the first one work, which gives me "-empty set-".

Comment: e.SUPER_SSN is the same as e.SUPER_SSN?

Comment: yes, i was expecting that it would display the super_ssn(supervisor).
But it didn't work,

Comment: except e.SUPER_SSN and e.SSN all other are same, check if this two contain data

Comment: they have data on them:
|Super_ssn:
333445555
888665555
333445555
333445555
(null)
888665555
987654321
987654321|

|ssn
123456789
333445555
453453453
666884444
888665555
987654321
987987987
999887777|

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already got an accepted query which gives you "Last name of employees in department 5 who work more than 10 hrs/week on productx" and all you're trying to do is find their supervisors, then you can simply select the `SUPER_SSN`s of those employees instead of their names, and then find the supervisors who have those SSNs.  Assuming supervisors are just `employees` (if they're in their own table, just substitute it in the outer query), it could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sup.LNAME FROM employees sup WHERE sup.ssn in
(
    SELECT e.SUPER_SSN FROM EMPLOYEE e , WORKS_ON w, PROJECT p
    WHERE e.DNO=5 AND e.SSN=w.ESSN AND w.PNO=p.PNUMBER AND p.PNAME='ProductX' AND HOURS>10
)
```

This nested query is NOT optimal but is easy to understand.  For a real solution, look into the possibility of joining to the employees table a second time, based on e.g. `emp2.ssn=e.super_ssn`.